# Are two congruent and similar invertible matrices orthogonally similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

More concretely, if $A,B\in GL(n,\mathbb R)$ are similar and congruent, that is, there exist $P,Q\in GL(n,\mathbb R)$ such that $PAP^T=B,QAQ^{-1}=B$, then does there always exist a $O\in O(n,\mathbb R)$ such that $OAO^T=B$? I've known that it holds when $n=1,2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let
$$
P=\pmatrix{1&1&0\\ 0&1&1\\ 0&0&1},
\quad A=P^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&-1&1\\ 0&1&-1\\ 0&0&1},
\quad B=P^T.
$$
Then $PAP^T=B$. Also, $A$ and $B$ are similar to each other because their Jordan forms are $P$. However, as $A$ and $B$ have different Frobenius norms, they are not orthogonally equivalent.